# Why does my code print addresses rather than array content?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and need help with this one . I want to print values of "C" but it keep printing it's address . Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int* test (int a[5], int b[5]) {
    int *c = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) c[i] = a[i]+b[i];
    return c;
}


int main() {
    int A[5] = {22, 33, 44, 55, 66};
    int B[5] = {22, 33, 44, 55, 66};
    int* C[10] = {test(A,B)};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout<< &C[i] <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks it advance.

Comment: Also stop using `new[]`. This is an 8 line program and you already managed to leak. Use `std::vector` instead. That will also fix this `int* C[10] = {test(A,B)}` bug btw.

Comment: I hope you understand when this finishes and you lose the `&` you're still going to be printing addresses (10 of them; 1 from your allocation and 9 NULL's). I'm fairly confident that wasn't your intention.

Comment: @BaummitAugen , I'm not sure what does that mean . tnx anyway, I will google it.

Comment: @kuki [Here ya go](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `&` on this line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout<< &C[i] <<endl;
```

So it is just

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) cout<< C[i] <<endl;
```

The `&` operator in that context literally means you want to take the address of that object, so it of no surprise that's what it's outputting.

Comment: prints all values as **0** , insted of 22,33,44 ... etc

Comment: Because your `test` function is incorrect and contains a number of bugs, including memory leaks

Comment: this acutally was answer to my question , so I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First `int* C[10] = {test(A,B)};` should be `int * C = test(A,B);` as you are creating the array in the function and returning a pointer to it.  Secondly you should call `delete [] C` at the end of main as you called `new[]` and every time you call `new[]` you should call `delete[]`.  Lastly you are using the address of operator (&) in `cout<< &C[i] <<endl;` which as it name says is going to give you the address of `C[i]` and not its value.

Answer (score 0):

& gives the address of the variable. Therefore &C[i] gives the address of ith element of array C. Simply print without &.